# C-Function to generate random 53-Bit numbers

Tags: c, random

I did wrote a function, with that I want to generate unique random numbers, which have not more than 53 Bit. I would be happy, if you do a critical look at the source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t cp_random_53bit(void)
{
    // max 53 Bit:
    // 0x0020000000000000LU == 9007199254740992
    // CBIT31          0x80000000U
    // CBIT52          0x0010000000000000LU
    uint64_t                result  = 0;
    struct drand48_data     dseed   = {0};
    long int                sr_init = 0;
    long int                lg1, lg2;
    sr_init = time(0) + clock();
    srand48_r(sr_init, &dseed);
    lrand48_r(&dseed, &lg1);    // returns 32 Bit value
    lrand48_r(&dseed, &lg2);
    if( sizeof(long int) == 4)
    {
        result = ((uint64_t)lg1 << 20) + lg2;
    }
    else if( sizeof(long int) == 8)
    {
        result = (lg1 << 20) + lg2;
    }
    return result;
}

// compile: gcc -g3 -o bit53id bit53id.c

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** env)
{
    uint64_t    val53;
    int         idx;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
    tzset();
    // show some values
    for(idx=0; idx < 25; idx++)
    {
        val53   = cp_random_53bit();
        printf("cp_random_53bit: %lu (%lX)\n", val53, val53);
    }
    // check for values greater than 0x0020000000000000LU -1LU
    for(idx = 0; idx < 10000000; idx++)
    {
        val53   = cp_random_53bit();
        if( val53 > 9007199254740991 )
            printf("cp_random_53bit returns %lu\n", val53);
    }
}
```

In my tests it was successfull many millions of numbers. I do not know how great the danger of a collision is.

I made tests with drand48_r too, to get double values. They are between 0.0 and 1.0 and I found no good way to convert them to 53 bit integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique random number"? What is the difference to a random number? Would you sacrifice some randomness to the uniqueness? Would you accept non-uniqueness for actual randomness?

Comment: What do you mean by "I would be happy, if you do a critical look at the source"? What problem does your program exhibit? You know that this community does not review working code, don't you?

Comment: Sounds more appropriate for the code review stack exchange.

Comment: True random numbers will cause collissions relatively quickly, search for "birthday paradox" for more details. Some pseudo random number generators might generate a long sequence of distinct values before repeating themself, but obviously it's not very random at all and if the security of your application depends on the unpredictability of your random numbers, you should obviously avoid such a PRNG.

Comment: Thank you very much. First I thought, that this is helpful for others too.
Thank you Erich: this is important!

Comment: mareb, "In my tests it was successfull many millions of numbers" --> given this bias due to `+`, I have doubts about the quality of your random number tests.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should only initialize the 48-bit pseudo-random number generator once at program startup, not every time you request a new number.
- as commented by *chux*, `lrand48_r` only generates 31 bits, so the expressions do not produce 53 bits of random contents: you only get 51 bits (20 + 31), and sometimes an extra bit (approximately one chance in 1 million), when the addition produces a larger result. The expression must be changed to generate exactly 53 uniformly distributed bits.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct drand48_data dseed;

void cp_random_53bit_init(void) {
    srand48_r(time(NULL) + clock(), &dseed);
}

uint64_t cp_random_53bit(void) {
    // max 53 Bit:
    long int lg1, lg2;
    lrand48_r(&dseed, &lg1);  // lg1 has 31 random bits
    lrand48_r(&dseed, &lg2);  // lg2 has 31 random bits
    // combine the bits to obtain 53 random bits
    return ((uint64_t)lg1 << (53 - 31)) ^ lg2;
}

// compile: gcc -g3 -o bit53id bit53id.c

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    uint64_t    val53;
    int         idx;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
    tzset();
    cp_random_53bit_init();

    // show some values
    for (idx = 0; idx < 25; idx++) {
        val53 = cp_random_53bit();
        printf("cp_random_53bit: %llu (%llX)\n",
               (unsigned long long)val53, (unsigned long long)val53);
    }
    // check for values greater than 0x0020000000000000LU -1LU
    for (idx = 0; idx < 10000000; idx++) {
        val53 = cp_random_53bit();
        if (val53 > 9007199254740991)
            printf("cp_random_53bit returns %llu\n", (unsigned long long)val53);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "only get 52 bits (20 + 32)." --> OP's addition will from time-to-time form a 53 bit sum.  Also by using addition a bias in the result occurs.  This answer is better, yet conceptually I would use `^` vs. `|` here, but that is a minor point.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the `|` combines 2 disjoint 32-bit words: `^` would produce the same result.  Do you advocate combining more bits from both calls, such as `result = ((uint64_t)lg1 << (53 -  32)) ^ lg2;`

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, something along that line of thought as `|`, `+` oblige disjoint sets whereas `^`, the sets may overlap.  Note that care is need with `lg1, lg2` due to sign extension and so they might not be disjoint.  Perhaps `((uint64_t)(uint32_t)lg1 << (53 -  32)) ^ (uint32_t)lg2`?  Hmmm, IMO, strange that `lrand48_r()` forms a _signed_ random number.

Comment: Oops, BTW, your code has a problem.  [`lrand48_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48) apparently only makes 31 random bits. Perhaps `((uint64_t)lg1 << (53 - 31)) ^ lg2`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: very good point! answer updated.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: masking should indeed be redundant. Answer updated.